# What does gzip < my file.gzip > do?

Tags: linux, gzip

I am playing around with Linux and came across gzip < my file.gzip >, and I wonder what it does.
Can someone tell me what it does?

Comment: Can you please check the command again and put it in code blocks so it is clear what it is? `< my file.gzip >` does not quite make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The `<` and `>` are shell constructs. `< file.txt` means treat `file.txt` as the input and `> file.txt` means treat `file.txt` as the output. The command might be something like this:

```
% gzip < input.gz > output.txt
```

This would take the gzipped (compressed) input file `input.gz` and write out an uncompressed version as `output.txt`. It might not be a text file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `gzip --help`?  That should answer your question about usage.

**Output from `gzip --help`:**

```
Usage: gzip [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Compress or uncompress FILEs (by default, compress FILES in-place).

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

  -c, --stdout      write on standard output, keep original files unchanged
  -d, --decompress  decompress
  -f, --force       force overwrite of output file and compress links
  -h, --help        give this help
  -k, --keep        keep (don't delete) input files
  -l, --list        list compressed file contents
  -L, --license     display software license
  -n, --no-name     do not save or restore the original name and time stamp
  -N, --name        save or restore the original name and time stamp
  -q, --quiet       suppress all warnings
  -r, --recursive   operate recursively on directories
  -S, --suffix=SUF  use suffix SUF on compressed files
  -t, --test        test compressed file integrity
  -v, --verbose     verbose mode
  -V, --version     display version number
  -1, --fast        compress faster
  -9, --best        compress better
  --rsyncable       Make rsync-friendly archive

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Report bugs to <bug-gzip@gnu.org>.
```